# Canvas transformation of grid to curvilinear grid

Tags: tikz-pgf, grids, technical-drawing

I would like to draw a curvilinear grid/mesh like this (sorry for freehand drawing)
[image: curvilinear grid]

I thought the easiest (and most elegant) solution would be to apply a canvas transformation to a regular `grid` in *TikZ*.

However, I found only this example in the *pgf/TikZ manual*, which rotates a grid:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf}
  \begin{document}
    \begin{pgfpicture}
    \pgftransformrotate{10}
    \pgfpathgrid[stepx=1mm,stepy=2mm]{\pgfpoint{0mm}{0mm}}{\pgfpoint{30mm}{30mm}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
  \end{pgfpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: rotated grid]

Do these kind of transformations exist or should I use the recommended solution in [this question on polar grids](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35263/tikz-polar-grid).

Comment: To my (limited) knowledge, the only transformations that are possible internally are affine and therefore not able to do what you want.  As evidence, note that the transformations act on the *coordinates* and not on the actual paths themselves, so a line stays a line whereas you want that line to transform to an arc.  So my thinking is that the polar grid question will be your best bet.

Answer (score 10):

Not exactly an answer because I think it's more complicated to transform a tool than to create  a new tool. Like Andrew says it's impossible in your case.

Here a macro : ( I made this code in few minutes also I think tikz's expert can do  a better macro with more options)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage,tikz} 
\makeatletter  
\pgfkeys{%
/polargrid/.cd,
rmin/.code ={\global\def\rmin {#1}},
rmax/.code ={\global\def\rmax {#1}},
amin/.code ={\global\def\amin {#1}},
amax/.code ={\global\def\amax {#1}},
rstep/.code={\global\def\rstep{#1}}, 
astep/.code={\global\def\astep{#1}}}

\def\polargrid{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\polar@grid}{\polar@grid[]}}%
\def\polar@grid[#1]{%
\pgfkeys{/polargrid/.cd,
rmin ={0},
rmax ={10},
amin ={0},
amax ={180},
rstep={1}, 
astep={10}}   
%
\pgfqkeys{/polargrid}{#1}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\addastep}{\amin+\astep} 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\addrstep}{\rmin+\rstep} 
 \foreach \a in {\amin,\addastep,...,\amax}  \draw[gray] (\a:\rmin) -- (\a:\rmax);  
 \foreach \r in {\rmin,\addrstep,...,\rmax}  \draw[gray] (\amin:\r cm) arc (\amin:\amax:\r cm);    
 } 
\makeatother   
\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.75] 
\polargrid
\end{tikzpicture}  

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.75] 
\polargrid[rmin=4,rmax=8,amin=20,amax=120]
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

[image]