# How to start a curvilinear bezier curve at a specific point?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm currently fiddling around with the pgf library `curvilinear`. What I want to do is make a shape bending like the shape of a `grid`, a `grid` very similar to this one: [Canvas transformation of grid to curvilinear grid](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44067/canvas-transformation-of-grid-to-curvilinear-grid)

One issue however, is that I cannot seem to spawn this `grid` at a designated place in my `tikzpicture`. How can I spawn the `grid` at say, point (0,-5) in my `tikzpicture`?

So basically, I want to create a flat amount of offset on the nonlinear transformation to then use it as a reference to make a rectangular curve wrapped across the grid (but that shouldn't be too much of an issue).

Code:

```
\documentclass[landscape,svgnames]{article}
\usepackage[a3paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,shapes.arrows,shadows,arrows,positioning,shapes}
\usepgflibrary{curvilinear}
\usepgfmodule{nonlineartransformations}

\makeatletter  
\pgfkeys{%
/polargrid/.cd,
rmin/.code ={\global\def\rmin {#1}},
rmax/.code ={\global\def\rmax {#1}},
amin/.code ={\global\def\amin {#1}},
amax/.code ={\global\def\amax {#1}},
rstep/.code={\global\def\rstep{#1}}, 
astep/.code={\global\def\astep{#1}}}

\def\polargrid{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\polar@grid}{\polar@grid[]}}%
\def\polar@grid[#1]{%
\pgfkeys{/polargrid/.cd,
rmin ={0},
rmax ={10},
amin ={0},
amax ={180},
rstep={1}, 
astep={10}}   
%
\pgfqkeys{/polargrid}{#1}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\addastep}{\amin+\astep} 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\addrstep}{\rmin+\rstep} 
 \foreach \a in {\amin,\addastep,...,\amax}  \draw[gray] (\a:\rmin) -- (\a:\rmax);  
 \foreach \r in {\rmin,\addrstep,...,\rmax}  \draw[gray] (\amin:\r cm) arc (\amin:\amax:\r cm);    
 } 
\makeatother  

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,node distance=1cm, auto,baseline=-.5ex]

\polargrid[rmin=4,rmax=8,amin=180,amax=360] at (5,0)

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not aware of such `curvilinear` library: could you point the source code?

Comment: For solvers: it is described on pages 1060+ in the [`TikZ3`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) manual.

Comment: You need to put things inside a scope to limit the effect then you can shift around that scope. Example; http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169624/creating-a-polar-grid-with-tikz/169761#169761 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167109/3235

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3235/percusse !

For simple reference you can find the code with the created offset by the `scope` environment below:

```
\documentclass[landscape,svgnames]{article}
\usepackage[a3paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,shapes.arrows,shadows,arrows,positioning,shapes}
\usepgflibrary{curvilinear}
\usepgfmodule{nonlineartransformations}

\makeatletter  
\pgfkeys{%
/polargrid/.cd,
rmin/.code ={\global\def\rmin {#1}},
rmax/.code ={\global\def\rmax {#1}},
amin/.code ={\global\def\amin {#1}},
amax/.code ={\global\def\amax {#1}},
rstep/.code={\global\def\rstep{#1}}, 
astep/.code={\global\def\astep{#1}}}

\def\polargrid{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\polar@grid}{\polar@grid[]}}%
\def\polar@grid[#1]{%
\pgfkeys{/polargrid/.cd,
rmin ={0},
rmax ={10},
amin ={0},
amax ={180},
rstep={1}, 
astep={10}}   
%
\pgfqkeys{/polargrid}{#1}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\addastep}{\amin+\astep} 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\addrstep}{\rmin+\rstep} 
 \foreach \a in {\amin,\addastep,...,\amax}  \draw[gray] (\a:\rmin) -- (\a:\rmax);  
 \foreach \r in {\rmin,\addrstep,...,\rmax}  \draw[gray] (\amin:\r cm) arc (\amin:\amax:\r cm);    
 } 
\makeatother  

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,node distance=1cm, auto,baseline=-.5ex]

\node (dummy) at (0,-5) {}; % create dummy node

\begin{scope}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(dummy.center)}] %create a shift using the scope environment
\polargrid[rmin=0,rmax=8,amin=180,amax=360]
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```