# Logarithmic Y Axis in pgfplots polar charts

Tags: pgfplots, polar

I am trying to use logarithmic Y Axis in pgfplots polar charts by specifying `ymode=log`:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{polaraxis}[
        ymode=log, ymin=0, ymax=70,
        ytick=\empty, axis y line=none, 
        xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}^\circ$,
        nodes near coords style={font=\footnotesize},
        nodes near coords=\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%,
        visualization depends on={x\as\myx},
        nodes near coords style={anchor=\myx-180},
    ]
    \addplot+ [polar comb, green, line width=3pt, mark=none, ->]
    coordinates {(0,21.6) (180,15.8)};
    \addplot+ [polar comb, red, line width=3pt, mark=none, ->]
    coordinates {(90,11.4) (270,10.6)};
    \addplot+ [mark=none, ->, polar comb, blue, line width=3pt]
    coordinates {(30,5.3) (60,5.5) (120,4.0) (150,6.6) (210,5.2) (240,5.5) (300,3.4) (330,5.2)};
    \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Issues:

1. The labels (nodes near coords) are also shown as log value. I just want log-scale of the y-axis, keeping the presented y values as are.
2. Many errors (on overleaf) regarding floating point: : Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit got an ill-formatted floating point number `2.75998000000000'. The unreadable part was near '2.75998000000000'..

Comment: Please have a look at [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/309268). It seems that there is no predefined way to do a logarithmic polar axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you can take advantage of the `point meta`, `y coord trafo` and `y coord inv trafo` keys.

`y coord trafo` and `y coord inv trafo` can apply a transformation on original `y` coordinates in order to modify the actual plot coordinates and associated tick labels. 
This is further explained in the [`pgfplots` manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) section 4.21 Symbolic Coordinates and User Transformations.

Basically what happens is

- `y coord trafo/.code = {<expression>}` takes the input `y` coordinates and parses `<expression>` using them;
- `y coord inv trafo/.code = {<inv expression>}` takes the results of the previous parse and parses  `<inv expression>` with them;
- `point meta = <setting>` sets the value of `pgfplotspointmeta` depending on the value of `<setting>`. As here you are interested in the `y` values, you could select `<setting>=y`, but since the `y` coordinates are parsed this would actually result in a bad output, so one can select `rawy` which corresponds to the actual unprocessed `y` values.

Here is the code

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{polaraxis}[
        ymin=1, ymax=70,
        xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}^\circ$,
        point meta ={rawy},
        y coord trafo/.code =\pgfmathparse{log10(#1)},
        y coord inv trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{10^#1},
        nodes near coords style={font=\footnotesize},
        nodes near coords=\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%,
        visualization depends on={x\as\myx},
        nodes near coords style={anchor=\myx-180},
    ]
    \addplot+ [polar comb, green, line width=3pt, mark=none, ->]
    coordinates {(0,21.6) (180,15.8)};
    \addplot+ [polar comb, red, line width=3pt, mark=none, ->]
    coordinates {(90,11.4) (270,10.6)};
    \addplot+ [mark=none, ->, polar comb, blue, line width=3pt]
    coordinates {(30,5.3) (60,5.5) (120,4.0) (150,6.6) (210,5.2) (240,5.5) (300,3.4) (330,5.2)};
    \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the ouput. I just removed the settings hiding the y axis so that you see the effect on the tick labels.

[image]

Comment: Excellent solution. Thanks! I struggle, however in integrating it with another solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538220/logarithmic-y-axis-colors-arrow-heads-in-pgfplots-polar-charts

Comment: You shouldn't have deleted the answer to the other question. Please see [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538229/logarithmic-y-axis-in-pgfplots-inaccurate-numbers#comment1359857_538229). You could also just post an answer there, then both of us have an answer... (I still think that the anchor adjustment in my answer is also helpful... ;-)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat will do !