# Logarithmic Y axis in pgfplots - Inaccurate Numbers

Tags: pgfplots, polar

Following [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/537868/logarithmic-y-axis-in-pgfplots-polar-charts) and [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538220/logarithmic-y-axis-colors-arrow-heads-in-pgfplots-polar-charts) regarding logarithmic Y axis in pgfplots polar charts, although the solution works great graphically, the numbers suffer from rounding errors during calculations. Any idea how to solve it?

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{polaraxis}[>=stealth,
        ymin=1, ymax=20000, ytick=\empty,
        point meta ={rawy},
        y coord trafo/.code =\pgfmathparse{log10(#1)},
        y coord inv trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{10^#1},
        xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}^\circ$,
        every axis plot/.append style={ultra thick},
        visualization depends on={x\as\myx},
        visualization depends on={y\as\myy},
        scatter/@pre marker code/.append code={
        \pgftransformreset
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{(abs(sin(\myx))<0.01 ? "green" :
        (abs(cos(\myx))<0.01 ? "red" : "blue"))}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\myanchoradd}{(abs(sin(\myx))<0.01 ?-90:0)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\myundoney}{pow(10,\myy)}
        \draw[->,color=\mycolor] (axis cs:0,1) -- 
        (axis cs:\myx,\myundoney) 
        node[anchor=\myx-180+\myanchoradd]{\pgfmathprintnumber{\myundoney}};
        },
    ]
    \addplot+ [scatter,draw=none]
    coordinates {
        (0,200.7)   (30,557.4)  (60,270.9)
        (90,82)     (120,399.7) (150,434.9)
        (180,345.7) (210,536.2) (240,256.3)
        (270,108.8) (300,365.1) (330,386.8)};
    \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In principle one could think of using `xfp`. Well, if it had a real manual, that is.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, i guess it's all about teamwork !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As poposed by Schrödinger's cat, here is my previously deleted proposal.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{polaraxis}[>=stealth,
        ymin=1, ymax=9500,
        %ytick=\empty, axis y line=none, 
        point meta ={rawy},
        y coord trafo/.code =\pgfmathparse{log10(#1)},
        y coord inv trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{10^#1},
        xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}^\circ$,
        every axis plot/.append style={ultra thick},
        visualization depends on={x\as\myx},
        visualization depends on={y\as\myy},
        scatter/@pre marker code/.append code={
        \pgftransformreset
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{(abs(sin(\myx))<0.01 ? "green" : (abs(cos(\myx))<0.01 ? "red" : "blue"))}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\myanchoradd}{(abs(sin(\myx))<0.01 ?-90:0)}
        \typeout{\myx,\myy,\mycolor}
        \draw[->,color=\mycolor] (axis cs:0,1) -- (axis cs:\myx,{10^\myy}) node[anchor=\myx-180+\myanchoradd]{\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%};
        },
    ]
    \addplot+ [scatter,draw=none]
    coordinates {
        (0,200.7)   (30,557.4)  (60,270.9)
        (90,82)     (120,399.7) (150,434.9)
        (180,345.7) (210,536.2) (240,256.3)
        (270,108.8) (300,365.1) (330,386.8)};
    \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat what did I tell you, teamwork ! Thanks for pointing the updates

Comment: Great answer!!!

Comment: Brilliant. Many thanks!